# Windows 8 tablet keyboard dock hard drive

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, ssd, docking-station

I've bought an ASUS TX300CA Windows 8 transformer tablet which has a detachable keyboard dock.

The tablet is a Core i7 machine and has serious power - so I want to use it to do sporadic and ad-hoc software development on it.

The tablet has a neat feature that although the detachable tablet part has only a 128Gb SSD, when you attach the keyboard dock, you get an additonal 500Gb of magnetic hard drive.

What I want to be able to do is to install applications so that they will install either completely on the tablet drive or completely on the dock drive.

For example, I'd like to put most of Microsoft Office on the tablet, but put say Microsoft Visual Studio on the dock drive.

Can this be done?  What's best practice for this?

TIA, 
Paolo

Comment: you have asked this on your other question http://superuser.com/questions/644682/windows-8-tablet-keyboard-dock-hard-drive

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly install software on an external drive, typically if "Advanced" is chosen during program installation, you can choose an alternate location for the install.

Obviously when you're not docked, you won't be able to use Visual Studio if it's installed on another drive. You'll also probably encounter some missing file errors if you try to use any context menus the program might install as well.

Finally, all of the registry information and any files or drivers (e.g. any files that would go into `%WINDIR%` or `system32`/`SysWOW64`) that need to be installed along with the software will be placed on your SSD or main Windows volume.

Comment: Thanks, @Josh R.  Say the alternate drive is A:, should I create both a Program Files and a Program Files (x86)  and try to mirror the locations on C: drive or can I just throw them all in together?

Comment: I don't believe it will make any difference.